# gcc 4.9.2 compilation error: AssetLinkData

Tags: c++, gcc

Trying to compile the program included below, I get the following error. What should be modified in the program for successful compilation?
Looks like GCC 4.9.2 can't implement some noexcept move constructors as "=default".

The line causing the trouble is:
    `AssetLinkData::AssetLinkData(AssetLinkData&& other) noexcept = default;`

---

> **COMPILATION ERROR:** FAILED: obj/browser/asset_link_data.o  g++ -MMD -MF (I removed many more flags)
>
> asset_link_data.cc: error: function
>   'password_manager::AssetLinkData::AssetLinkData(password_manager::AssetLinkData&&)'
>   defaulted on its redeclaration with an exception-specification that
>   differs from the implicit declaration
>   'password_manager::AssetLinkData::AssetLinkData(password_manager::AssetLinkData&&)'
>   AssetLinkData::AssetLinkData(AssetLinkData&& other) noexcept =
>   default;

---

**SOURCE CODE:**

```
#include "asset_link_data.h"

#include <algorithm>

#include <utility>

#include "base/json/json_reader.h"

#include "base/json/json_value_converter.h"

#include "base/values.h"

namespace password_manager { namespace {

constexpr char kGetLoginsRelation[] =
    "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"; constexpr char kWebNamespace[] = "web";

}  // namespace

AssetLinkData::AssetLinkData() = default;

AssetLinkData::AssetLinkData(AssetLinkData&& other) noexcept = default;

AssetLinkData::~AssetLinkData() = default; AssetLinkData& AssetLinkData::operator=(AssetLinkData&& other) = default;  
}  // namespace password_manager
```

below Im adding the contents of asset_link_data.h:

```
#ifndef COMPONENTS_PASSWORD_MANAGER_CORE_BROWSER_SITE_AFFILIATION_ASSET_LINK_DATA_H_
#define COMPONENTS_PASSWORD_MANAGER_CORE_BROWSER_SITE_AFFILIATION_ASSET_LINK_DATA_H_

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "base/macros.h"
#include "url/gurl.h"

namespace password_manager {

// The class parses an asset link file. The spec for the format is
// https://github.com/google/digitalassetlinks/blob/master/well-known/details.md
// The class cares only about two types of statements:
// - includes. Those are just a reference to a file to be loaded and parsed.
// - "get_login_creds" permission to a web page. That means that the target is
//   allowed to get the credentials saved for the source.
// Only HTTPS URLs are taken into account.
class AssetLinkData {
 public:
  AssetLinkData();
  AssetLinkData(AssetLinkData&& other) noexcept;
  ~AssetLinkData();

  AssetLinkData& operator=(AssetLinkData&& other);

  bool Parse(const std::string& data);

  const std::vector<GURL>& includes() const { return includes_; }
  const std::vector<GURL>& targets() const { return targets_; }

 private:
  std::vector<GURL> includes_;
  std::vector<GURL> targets_;

  DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(AssetLinkData);
};

}  // namespace password_manager
#endif  // COMPONENTS_PASSWORD_MANAGER_CORE_BROWSER_SITE_AFFILIATION_ASSET_LINK_DATA_H_
```

Comment: Where is `AssetLinkData` defined?

Comment: Kevin:
I removed the include statements from the code. The first include says the following:

#include "asset_link_data.h"

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the definition of `AssetLinkData`? And get rid of everything else that's not relevant to the error (`Target`, `Statement`, `AssetLinkData::Parse` etc).

Comment: I have edited the question per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear:

> defaulted on its redeclaration with an exception-specification that differs from the implicit declaration

You have asked for the compiler to go ahead and define the constructor the way it was going to anyway, but you have *also* asked for the constructor to be `noexcept` ... and the default created constructor is not `noexcept`

To fix this, you either need to remove the `noexcept` specifier:

```
AssetLinkData::AssetLinkData(AssetLinkData&& other) = default;
```

or, if you want a no-except specifier, you need to crank it out by hand the old-fashioned way:

```
AssetLinkData::AssetLinkData(AssetLinkData&& other) noexcept
: includes_(std::move(other.includes_))
, targets_ (std::move(other.targets_ ))
{}
```

Comment: and how can I fix this error? What should be modified in the code? I have edited the question with more relevant information...

Comment: If I remove the `noexcept` specifier, am I changing the way the program behaves or this is only a cosmetic change? Im trying to compile the source code for the chrome browser to use it on a daily basis and this is the only file (out of thousands more) causing me trouble...

Comment: You are changing the way it behaves (or at least, the way it *may* behave).  `noexcept` is not purely cosmetic.

Comment: Then I have to use the old-fashined way to stick to the original program or it also changes the behavior?

Comment: Yes.  But I am *slightly* puzzled.  The Chrome source code compiles, so why are you getting compilation errors?  (Comments are not a suitable place to discuss that.  You would have to create a new question, with a *lot* more detail.)